# Are resources recreated by Terraform when 'count' argument is changed?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, devops

I am currently working on a module which requires to have a flexible amount of IP addresses.

At the moment, my resource count is 5. What would happen if I increased the number_of_ips to 6 or more? Would Terraform recreate all 6 IP address resources or would it incrementally add another resource?

Example:

```
locals {
  number_of_ips = 5
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public-ip" {
  count               = local.number_of_ips
  name                = "${var.name}${count.index}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = var.allocation_method
  sku                 = var.sku
}
```

In the example above, when going from `number_of_ips = 5` to `number_of_ips = 6`, are IP addresses 1 through 5 being recreated or are we just adding IP address #6 as an incremental change?

Comment: It should only add a new one.

Comment: Hi Samuel, that's a valid point, however, I do not currently have an existing subscription I could use for testing. It would also require me to create the infrastructure around it (virtual network, subnets, resource groups, etc). 'Terraform plan' alone does not give us the answer I am looking for, I would have to actually deploy these resources and then run it iteratively again, which also incurs costs.

Comment: @Macko `terraform plan` should show you if it's replacing resources that already exist or just adding a new one, which you can verify in the output of the plan command.

Comment: I do not have any existing resources in place unfortunately to compare against

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the point of the exercise if you cannot test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform is a desired-state system, which means that it evaluates your configuration with the goal of understanding essentially "what you want the world to look like", and then compares that with its records of what the world currently looks like and proposes a set of actions to get from the current state to the desired state.

Between runs Terraform remembers which resource instances exist, and so if you initially run with `count = 5` Terraform will be tracking the following addresses in its state:

- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[0]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[1]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[2]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[3]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[4]`

When you run Terraform again with `count = 6`, which means that the *desired state* will contain an additional address:

- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[0]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[1]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[2]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[3]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[4]`
- `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[5]` ⬅️ **this one is new**

Terraform will therefore compare the desired state with the actual state for indices zero through four, and hopefully find that the desired state matches those existing objects and so determine that nothing needs to change.

Terraform will also notice that `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[5]` didn't exist at all before, and so will ask the AzureRM provider to plan to create a new object matching that instance's desired state.

Therefore the typical behavior in the situation you described would be Terraform proposing only to create `azurerm_public_ip.public-ip[5]`, and not making any proposals at all for the other instances.